# MySQL GROUP BY with specific values and remaining as 'other'

Tags: mysql, sql, count, case, aggregate-functions

I have a `how did you hear about us?` form field when user register. Now with the data collected i'm trying to find percentage of each option.  The issue i'm having is any user that has filled in `other`, i can't use group by method because they typed something different.  How do i group by anything that isn't in the options as `other`?

```
user  |  how_heard
user1 |  facebook
user2 |  youtube
user3 |  facebook
user4 |  instagram
user5 |  advert
user6 |  facebook
user7 |  browsing the internet
user8 |  promotional tag
user9 |  university recommended me
```

The last three users, should be grouped as `other`.  How do i do this?

Here is my query, it works but not with the values typed in `other`.

```
SELECT ma.how_heard
     , COUNT(1) AS total
     , COUNT(1) / t.cnt * 100 AS `percentage`
  FROM users ma
 CROSS
  JOIN (SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM users) t
 GROUP
    BY ma.how_heard
     , t.cnt
```

Comment: `GROUP BY FIND_IN_SET(how_heard, 'facebook, youtube, .. , advert')`. The values from the list will form separate groups, all non-listed values will be treated as one separate group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN u.how_heard IN ('facebook', 'youtube', 'instagram', 'advert')
        THEN u.how_heard
        ELSE 'other'
    END as how_heard_new,
    COUNT(*) AS total,
    COUNT(*) / t.cnt * 100 AS `percentage`
FROM users u 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM users) t
GROUP BY how_heard_new, t.cnt
```

Note that, if you are running MySQL 8.0, you can replace the subquery with a window sum:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN u.how_heard IN ('facebook', 'youtube', 'instagram', 'advert')
        THEN u.how_heard
        ELSE 'other'
    END as how_heard_new,
    COUNT(*) AS total,
    COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER() * 100 AS `percentage`
FROM users u 
GROUP BY how_heard_new
```